# The element '<field name="name">' cannot be located on parent view

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I'm trying to add this field `name` to the treeview of `fleet_vehicle_log_services` model in Odoo v9 community.

So, on the parent view we got field `date` as the first field in the view, then on an inherited model, I've added `name` and I want to add it to the treeview, before `date` like this:

```
    <record id="fleet_stock_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">fleet.vehicle.log.services.tree</field>
        <field name="model">fleet.vehicle.log.services</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref='fleet.fleet_vehicle_log_services_tree'/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="date" position="before"/>
                <field name="name"/>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Funny thing, is that I've tried this way before, on other models, and it worked just fine, here, it seems, it isn't taking the actual parent field, so somehow it takes the `name` field as if it is on the parent view, but it isn't, what am I doing wrong here?

Do I need `xpath` for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<record id="fleet_stock_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">fleet.vehicle.log.services.tree</field>
    <field name="model">fleet.vehicle.log.services</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref='fleet.fleet_vehicle_log_services_tree'/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='date']" position="before">
            <field name="name"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

You don't need xpath especially for this case, you just need to put the field name **inside** the field date.
Have this

```
<field name="date" position="before"/>
<field name="name"/>
```

become this

```
<field name="date" position="before">
    <field name="name"/>
</field>
```

You need to use xpath to select hard to select elements. Like the fifth div inside a div whose class is "some-class".

Comment: Cool, maybe that was it, going to check it out, would be nice :)